# Storing Lambdas in Dictionary

Tags: python, lambda, closures

I am trying to store lambda functions in a python dictionary. It seems that the loop overwrites all of the data stored in the dictionary with the last lambda. For example:

```
example_dict = {}
for i in range(5):
    example_dict[i] = lambda x: x + i

for key, func in example_dict.items():
    print(key, func(10))
```

Should output

```
0 10
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
```

But the actual output is:

```
0 14
1 14
2 14
3 14
4 14
```

This is very interesting to me. Anybody know why the last lambda function overwrites all of the other data in the dictionary?

Comment: Just discovered this, and appreciate the answer, but this behaviour feels like a bug in python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not overwriting the last `lambda`, they *all* point to the final value of `i` in the `for` loop because of how closures work. You can avoid it by giving the `lambda` functions a default argument:

```
example_dict = {}

for i in range(5):
    example_dict[i] = lambda x, i=i: x + i

for key, func in example_dict.items():
    print(key, func(10))
```

Output with change:

```
0 10
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
```

Comment: `(lambda i:(lambda x:x + i))(i)` if you want to force a single argument lambda.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz: Sure…but why complicate things?